# X11: invalid Alt/Meta key config? / GTK+: said key not mapped by gdk_keymap_add_virtual_modifiers()? / KDE: bogus complaint about key?

Tags: keyboard, gtk, x11, kde-plasma, gdk

**NOTE** See the updates below; weirder things have come up now.

I'm interpreting the `GdkEvent***.state` field in my various mouse event handlers as so:

```
gdk_keymap_add_virtual_modifiers(
    gdk_keymap_get_for_display(gdk_window_get_display(e.window)),
    (GdkModifierType *) &e.state);
// (gdk_keymap_get_default() has the same effect)
```

however, this does not seem to map in `GDK_META_MASK` properly when I hit the Alt key.

`e.state` appears to be 0x18 (`MOD1`|`MOD2`) when I hit either Alt key. I wrote a small C program (below) to print what GDK thinks the physical keycodes should be, and it returns (output reformatted for clarity)

```
        gdk_keymap_map_virtual_modifiers output           gboolean return from that
meta    0x10000000                                        1
super   0x4000040                                         1
hyper   0x8000040                                         1
```

xmodmap says

```
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_R (0x6c),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

What's going on? I'm running GTK+/GDK 3.10.7 but my program targets GTK+ 3.4 at minimum. Thanks.

```
// pietro gagliardi 19 march 2014
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

GdkKeymap *def;

void dovirt(char *name, GdkModifierType mod)
{
    GdkModifierType from, to;
    gboolean mapped;

    from = mod;
    gdk_keymap_add_virtual_modifiers(def, &from);
    to = mod;
    mapped = gdk_keymap_map_virtual_modifiers(def, &to);
    printf("%s\t0x%X\t0x%X\t%d:0x%X\n",
        name, mod, from, mapped, to);
}

int main(void)
{
    gtk_init(NULL, NULL);
    def = gdk_keymap_get_default();
    printf("name\tmod\tadd\tmap\n");
    dovirt("meta", GDK_META_MASK);
    dovirt("super", GDK_SUPER_MASK);
    dovirt("hyper", GDK_HYPER_MASK);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Update 22 March 2014

After running kate in sudo to edit something, I see this in the command line:

```
kglobalaccel(19598) KKeyServer::initializeMods: Your keyboard setup doesn't provide a key to use for meta. See 'xmodmap -pm' or 'xkbcomp $DISPLAY' 
kglobalaccel(19598) KKeyServer::initializeMods: Your keyboard setup doesn't provide a key to use for meta. See 'xmodmap -pm' or 'xkbcomp $DISPLAY' 
kglobalaccel(19598) KKeyServer::initializeMods: Your keyboard setup doesn't provide a key to use for meta. See 'xmodmap -pm' or 'xkbcomp $DISPLAY'
```

`xmodmap -pm` just says what I pasted above for xmodmap; `xkbcomp $DISPLAY` produces no output and exit status 0. And Alt seems to work elsewhere... including kate. Now I'm really confused

#### Update 23 March 2014

Now interpreting `key-press-event`/`key-release-event`; `GdkKeyEvent.keyval` return `GDK_KEY_Alt_L` and `GDK_KEY_Alt_R`...

Comment: I think the baseline issue is that there are 2 sets of integers representing keys which do not necessarily map on each other (I can not remember which ones these were).